# Base64Encoding is deprecated : first deprecated in iOS 7.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, image, base64

I've downloaded the Base64 library from GitHub.I used it in my project to decode the Images from webserver. I made this project for iOS7.0 The warning am getting with base64 is:

`'base64Encoding' is deprecated : first deprecated in iOS7.0.`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Started from iOS 7 SDK , [NSData class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html) now has methods that help encode/decode base 64 data and string objects with the following:

```
- (instancetype)initWithBase64EncodedData:(NSData *)base64Data
                                  options:(NSDataBase64DecodingOptions)options

- (instancetype)initWithBase64EncodedString:(NSString *)base64String
                                    options:(NSDataBase64DecodingOptions)options
```

Once you got your NSData instances initialize a UIImage object with: + (UIImage *)imageWithData:(NSData *)data

types of encoding:

```
 - NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength     
   NSDataBase64Encoding76CharacterLineLength     
   NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithCarriageReturn     
   NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed
```

types of decoding:

```
- NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters
```

Comment: Whats the difference between NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength and NSDataBase64Encoding76CharacterLineLength

Comment: there varies RFC specs out there see [wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Implementations_and_history). NSData has to support all length, there not much difference apart from maximum length and when to insert the line break